# Spring-Velocity: Passing a Map to controller

Tags: spring-mvc, velocity

The $lists variable in the below file is populated with model-attribute from the controller. Every list assigned to the user must have an approver. This approver is not populated on page load, but is populated later by an ajax call and jquery.

**new.vm**

```
 <form class="common_form_body audience_member" method="post"    
        action="#springUrl("/account/users")">
        <fieldset class="common_form_group">
            <legend class="common_form_group_title">
                <span class="field_title">Basic Information</span>
                <span class="common_form_must_have">*</span>
            </legend>
            <ul class="common_form_group_body">
                <li>#formInput("user.email", "Email:", "maxlength='128' autofocus")</li>
                <li>
                    #formInput("user.firstName", "Name:", "maxlength='32'")
                    #formInput("user.lastName", "", "maxlength='32'")
                </li>
                <li>
                    #formInput("user.mobilePhone", "Mobile Phone:", "maxlength='32'")
                </li>
            </ul>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
           <ul>
                  #foreach($list in $lists)
                  <li>
                      <input type="checkbox" value="$list.id" />
                      <label>$list.name</label>
                      <select class="listapprover">
                          <option selected="selected">Choose Approver</option>  
                      </select>
                  </li>
                  #end
              </ul>
       </fieldset>

        <div class="common_form_control">
            <button name="create" class="common_form_submit icon_button" type="submit">
                <span class="create">Create</span>
            </button>
            <a class="common_form_cancel" href="#springUrl("/account/users")">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Now on form post I want to have a map that contains all the selected lists with their corresponding approvers.

Any idea how to bind such a map in the controller?

Comment: What controller do you want to bind the map to?

Comment: When you say "on form post"... do you actually mean on submitting the form... this would be strange as you're populating form fields after submitting the form which would surely be needed by the user before the form is submitted?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're rendering the velocity template server side... if that's the case then you won't be using velocity to handle your map of approvers in any way.

I think your question is a jquery/ajax one. You can bind the form submit action in jquery as below:

```
$form = $('form');
$form.on('submit', function(e){
    // get a map and do something with it
});
```